# Undefined index: aksi

Tags: php, database, crud

Hi i'm getting an error as :Undefined index: aksi in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\lat1.php on line 6 my php code is:

```
    <?php
include"class_koneksi.php";
$db=new database();
$db->konek();

if($_GET['aksi']==''){ //line 6

    $daftar=$db->tampilData();
        echo"<table border=1>
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Nama</td>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>Pesan</td>
                <td>Edit</td>
                <td>Hapus</td>
            </tr>";
    foreach($daftar as $data){
        echo" <tr>
                <td>".$data['id']."</td>
                <td>".$data['nama']."</td>
                <td>".$data['email']."</td>
                <td>".$data['pesan']."</td>
                <td><a href='?aksi=edit&id=$data[id]'>edit</a></td>
                <td><a href='?aksi=hapus_data&id=$data[id]'>Hapus</a></td>
            </tr>";
    }
    echo"</table> <br> <a href='?aksi=tambah'>TAMBAH</a>";


}elseif($_GET['aksi']=='tambah'){
    echo"<br>
    <form method=POST action='?aksi=tambah_data'>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Nama</td><td><input type=text name='nama'></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type=text name='email'></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Pesan</td><td><input type=text name='pesan'></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><input type=submit value='simpan'></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    ";

}
elseif($_GET['aksi']=='tambah'){
echo"<br>
<form method=POST action='?aksi=tambah_data'>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Nama</td><td><input type=text name='nama'></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type=text name='email'></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Pesan</td><td><input type=text name='pesan'></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><input type=submit value='simpan'></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
";
```

}

can you tell me what problem from this code if($_GET['aksi']=='')
is there any1 who cud help me out of this

thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+undefined+index+get

Answer (score 3):

**Replace**

```
if($_GET['aksi']==''){
```

**with**

```
if(isset($_GET['aksi']) && $_GET['aksi'] ==''){
```

because if you did not pass `$_GET['aksi']` then it will show you error